# Angular 2 with Html5 application cache

Tags: angular, html5-appcache, offlineapps

I have angular 2 website. I want to use html 5 application cache mechanism for this website to creating offline app for browsers. is it possible? if it is can you guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,
It is possible through concept of service-worker, which should work in majority of the browsers.

you can do that using this

```
<script>
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js').then(function(registration) {
      console.log('Service Worker registered');
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log('Service Worker registration failed: ', err);
    });
  }
</script>
```

Next you need to include service worker JS in index.html.

For caching Google Maintains sw-precache

Useful Links
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache

https://coryrylan.com/blog/fast-offline-angular-apps-with-service-workers